# Convert output to a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, jira

I have the below data from JIRA. I am trying to have this converted into a pandas Dataframe.

Here is my code:

```
from jira import JIRA

jiraOptions = {'server': 'https://**********.atlassian.net'}

jira = JIRA(options=jiraOptions, basic_auth=(
    '*******@gmail.com', '******************'))

project = 'project = GDI'

lista = []

for issue in jira.search_issues(jql_str=project):
        print('{} | {} | {} | {} {} | {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |'.format(issue.key,
                                                                    issue.fields.project.name,
                                                                    issue.fields.summary,
                                                                    issue.fields.issuetype,
                                                                    issue.fields.status,
                                                                    issue.fields.priority,
                                                                    issue.fields.reporter.displayName,
                                                                    issue.fields.created,
                                                                    issue.fields.assignee,                                     
                                                                    issue.fields.description,))
```

**Expected output :**

```
issue key:      Project name:       summary:               issue type:     assignee:
GDI-6           PROJECTBLABLA       Summaryblabla          epictodo        Nova
GDI-5           PROJECTBLABLA       Summaryblabla          epictodo        Nova
GDI-4           PROJECTBLABLA       Summaryblabla          epictodo        Nova
GDI-3           PROJECTBLABLA       Summaryblabla          epictodo        Nova
```

Is there a smart way to do it? I'm really stuck.. All what I know is that I need a list for that, right? So I need to put every details into their corresponding list, instead of printing them, then I work on pandas.

Thanks in advance,

Nova

Comment: What is printing now?

Comment: I can't post a picture but it prints the information that I asked for in the code above.. Its value I meant

Comment: I don't undertand what you said. prints what you asked for?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the output of my code:

```
DI-6 | Data Integration | Create Jenkins Job to automatise the collect of data  | Task To Do | Medium | Nova | 2022-07-04T12:10:03.155+0000 | Nova | Create Jenkins Job to automatise the collect of data daily |
DI-5 | Data Integration | Create SQL Tables | Task Done | Medium | Nova | 2022-07-04T11:56:21.925+0000 | Nova | Table tickets contain The fields of Jira Ticket (like Ticket number ,Summary , Description , Sprint ,Status ,�.)

Table Ticket_History : This table contain Ticket number, user ,Date & time , Field name ,Original Value , new value  |
DI-4 | Data Integration | Create Script python | Task In Progress | Medium | Nova | 2022-07-04T11:52:57.416+0000 | Nova | * Find the API that helps you to collect and extract the data from Jira 
* Insert the collected data in SQL data base  |
DI-2 | Data Integration | Install Environnement  | Task Done | Medium | Nova | 2022-07-04T11:49:08.332+0000 | Nova | Install Environnement |
DI-1 | Data Integration | Jira Data Integration Into SQL Data Base | Epic To Do | Medium | Nova | 2022-07-04T11:47:46.636+0000 | Nova | Jira Data Integration Into SQL Data Base |
```

After using this :

```
lista = []
for issue in jira.search_issues(jql_str=project):
   lista.append([issue.key, issue.fields.project.name, issue.fields.summary ...])
```

Here is the output:

```
[['DI-6', 'Data Integration', 'Create Jenkins Job to automatise the collect of data ', <JIRA IssueType: name='Task', id='10002'>, <JIRA Status: name='To Do', id='10000'>, <JIRA Priority: name='Medium', id='3'>, 'Nova', '2022-07-04T12:10:03.155+0000', <JIRA User: displayName='Nova', accountId='62c1b708ce5a604dbfb34700'>, 'Create Jenkins Job to automatise the collect of data daily'], ['DI-5', 'Data Integration', 'Create SQL Tables', <JIRA IssueType: name='Task', id='10002'>, <JIRA Status: name='Done', id='10002'>, <JIRA Priority: name='Medium', id='3'>, 'Nova', '2022-07-04T11:56:21.925+0000', <JIRA User: displayName='Nova', accountId='62c1b708ce5a604dbfb34700'>, 'Table tickets contain The fields of Jira Ticket (like Ticket number ,Summary , Description , Sprint ,Status ,�.)\n\nTable Ticket_History : This table contain Ticket number, user ,Date & time , Field name ,Original Value , new value '], ['DI-4', 'Data Integration', 'Create Script python', <JIRA IssueType: name='Task', id='10002'>, <JIRA Status: name='In Progress', id='10001'>, <JIRA Priority: name='Medium', id='3'>, 'Nova', '2022-07-04T11:52:57.416+0000', <JIRA User: displayName='Nova', accountId='62c1b708ce5a604dbfb34700'>, '* Find the API that helps you to collect and extract the data from Jira \n* Insert the collected data in SQL data base '], ['DI-2', 'Data Integration', 'Install Environnement ', <JIRA IssueType: name='Task', id='10002'>, <JIRA Status: name='Done', id='10002'>, <JIRA Priority: name='Medium', id='3'>, 'Nova', '2022-07-04T11:49:08.332+0000', <JIRA User: displayName='Nova', accountId='62c1b708ce5a604dbfb34700'>, 'Install Environnement'], ['DI-1', 'Data Integration', 'Jira Data Integration Into SQL Data Base', <JIRA IssueType: name='Epic', id='10004'>, <JIRA Status: name='To Do', id='10000'>, <JIRA Priority: name='Medium', id='3'>, 'Nova', '2022-07-04T11:47:46.636+0000', <JIRA User: displayName='Nova', accountId='62c1b708ce5a604dbfb34700'>, 'Jira Data Integration Into SQL Data Base']]
```

Why it adds <Jira and name="" and Id="" ... ? Idk :(

Comment: This is not an answer.  Please, consider giving answer feedback by comentários the answer post.  Also, delete this answer after doing this.  This way we keep answers reliable.  Best reguards.

Comment: for this, you can edit your own post.  Keep answer for answers only.   Check stack overflow Guide.   I am Just giving you a positive feedback.

Answer (score 1):

After hours and hours.. I found out the all I had to do is adding .name after                                                                     issues fields, like that:

```
issue.fields.summary,
issue.fields.issuetype.name,
issue.fields.status.name,
issue.fields.priority.name,
issue.fields.reporter.displayName,
issue.fields.created,
issue.fields.assignee.displayName,
```

**Thanks for your efforts for trying to help.**

Answer (score 0):

I am not too sure if this solves your problem:

```
lista = []
for issue in jira.search_issues(jql_str=project):
   lista.append([issue.key, issue.fields.project.name, issue.fields.summary ...])
```

Then you can make a dataframe from this.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(lista)
df.columns = ['issue key:', 'Project name:', 'summary:' ...]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, It worked but not the way I wanted it to be :( ,

Comment: How you expect your output?

Comment: I think the problem is from the Jira module, it worked with this solution but the values have been changed inside the lists, I know it's hard to understand just because I' cant post images of the output before and after the solution..